# How to split a file-path in shell script? As per my need

Tags: shell, sh, split

Splitting a string `str="directory1/src/main/java"` into an array containing

```
directory1
directory1/src
directory1/src/main
directory1/src/main/java
```

I need to do this so that I can create the folders necessary from inside a shell script (that's the reason why I need the array to contain the string in the format that has been provided

Comment: Look at `-p` option to `mkdir` - it creates intervening directories automagically... i.e. `mkdir -p directory1/src/main/java`

Comment: Post this as an answer so that I can choose this as the answer. Thank you. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe have a look at the `-p` option to `mkdir` - it creates intervening directories automagically...

```
mkdir -p directory1/src/main/java
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you can use `mkdir -p` without needing this kind of split. But, if you're curious, you can use the following code:

```
IFS="/" read -a components <<< "$str"
for((i=1; i<=${#components[@]}; i++)); do
  dir=$(IFS="/"; printf "%s" "${components[*]:0:i}")
  paths+=( "$dir" )
done
```

This splits the string into its component directories, then joins progressively longer prefixes of that array into strings.

Comment: Sorry, no. I forgot I was browsing the `shell` tag, not `bash`.